# Spontaneous emission as unitary time evolution

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

I have read in some articles that spontaneous emission could be considered as unitary time evolution. But when we talk about spontaneous emission, we talk of emission with random phase and in random direction. So I don't understand how this randomness comes up from unitary time evolution of any system.

Comment: Which articles?

Comment: If one were to keep track of all the vacuum modes, the combined atom-vacuum system would undergo unitary time evolution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission

Comment: Possibly related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258256/109928